# Retrieving SHA from gitpython when User is not Owner of Cloned Repo on Windows 11?

Tags: python, windows, git, gitpython

I am using the gitpython library to obtain the SHA of Python code during execution on a Windows 11 Enterprise PC. It works fine when I do it as I cloned the repo. When another user tries to run the code it fails unless they enter "git config --global --add safe.directory" at the command line first. If that user is not an admin on the PC, they have to enter that git config command at the command line every time they log in.

Is there a way to reliably get the SHA of Python code as it executes regardless of the user logged in?

This is the function I use to obtain the git SHA:

```
import git # note gitpython is what needs to be installed
def gitsha() -> str:
    try:
        repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
        sha = repo.head.object.hexsha
        return sha[-8:]
    except:
        return "ERROR"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to do this. The first word of `git ls-remote /path/to/repo HEAD` is probably the quickest and cleanest, and it doesn't even need a local repo, you can also use any url.

If you're doing more than just checking refs, reference aka shared-objects aka alternate-object-source clones are very handy.

With shell commands,

```
git clone -ns path/to/repo `mktemp -d`
git -C $_ rev-parse @
```

and you can add `--template= --single-branch --no-tags --bare` ot the clone options for extra purity points and often less speed gain than it took to type that in this use.

What's gong on is, git executing in a repo will use its configs, and some git commands wind up invoking hooks and helper commands. If you're using someone else's repository the commands they have configured may be a surprise, even an unpleasant one, so Git added checking for repositories-owned-by-others, and the `safe.directory` list.

How you get gitpython to do this, I leave as "an exercise for the reader". Yeah, that's it.